# On selecting a textfield, adjust view height for keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, xib

I have a ViewController (login view) in xib which has 2 `UITextField` and 1 `UIButton` component. The view hierarchy is

```
 UIView
     -> UIScrollView
         -> UIView (contentView)
             -> UITextField
             -> UITextField
             -> UIButton
```

I am using autolayout for the view. The UIScrollView has 4 constraints i.e., leading, trailing, top & bottom aligned to its superview (`UIViewController` view). ContentView has 4 constraints i.e., leading, trailing, top & bottom to its superview (UIScrollView) and width matching `UIViewController` view.

I have followed the steps as in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) to scroll up or down when user selects `UITextField` so that keyboard is not on top of `UITextField`.

When keyboard is shown scrollview is scrolled up but when keyboard is hidden scrollview does not scroll back. Any help is appreciated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

        let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    } 

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let activeField = self.activeField, let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)

            self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

            var aRect = self.view.frame

            aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.size.height
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)) {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollView `contentInset.top` was not `0.0` hence i was facing the problem. After changing `contentInset.top` properly scrollView set to original position after keyboard was hidden.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.scrollView.contentInset.top, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeField = self.activeField {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem with the keyboard is explained in detail in the apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Alternatively, try the following code:

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name:       NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name:    NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){
   self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
   var info = notification.userInfo!
   let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
   let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

   self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
   self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

   var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
   aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
   if let activeField = self.activeField {
       if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
           self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
       }
   }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
   var info = notification.userInfo!
   let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
   let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
   self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
   self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
   self.view.endEditing(true)
   self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
   activeField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
   activeField = nil
}
```

Comment: I have modified my keyboardWillBeHidden function as per suggestion but still i don't see scrollview returning to earlier position.